# Django SlugField "This field is required" error

Tags: django, slugify

In my django project there's a Blog model which I'm willing to create a slug for it's title:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(default='', max_length=100, verbose_name=u'عنوان')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, allow_unicode=True)
    # other stuffs
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title, allow_unicode=True)
        super(Blog, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slug
```

In django admin I don't fill slug field and when I hit the save button it says:

> This field is required.

Isn't my code suppose to create slug automatically? Is there something else I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `blank=True` for your slug field. This way it won't be required and it will be set to slugified title when save method will run.

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(default='', max_length=100, verbose_name=u'عنوان')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, allow_unicode=True, blank=True)
```